# The restriction to torsion of an epimorphism need not be an epimorphsim

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, modules

I am reading the book "Algebra" by Hungerford, and being troubled by problem 11(f) on Ch.4 Sec.1.

The problem is as follows:

> If $g : B \to C$ is an $R$-module epimorphism, then $g_T : T(B) \to T(C)$ need not be an epimorphism.[Hint: consider abelian groups.](Here $R$ is an integral domain)

I think the hint was meant to be used with the fact that every abelian group homomorphism is a $\mathbb Z$-module homomorphism, but I am not sure how to choose them.

Comment: Can you find a torsionfree abelian group that surjects onto a  torsion abelian group?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin I think $\mathbb Z \to {\mathbb Z \over (2)}$ is one?

Comment: Well, then chase it down and check if that works. Note: I would write $\frac{\mathbb{Z}}{2\mathbb{Z}}$. $2$ is not a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ah, right! Thank you! Also thanks for the note, I edited my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Look at $0 \mapsto \mathbb{Z} \mapsto \mathbb{Q} \mapsto \mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z} \mapsto 0$.
Then apply the functor which restricts to, say, 2 torsion.
Then $\mathbb{Q}$ has no $2$-torsion, but the 2-part of $\mathbb{Q}/\mathbb{Z}$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/2$.